# Mule GZip Compress

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Hi i am using anypoint studio 2014 release, and i need to create two flows, the first flow needs to receive a fixed width file and then compress it into a gzip file and the send it out, the second flow is suppose to get a gzip file, decompress it, and send on the fixed width file. I have not done the second flow yet but i am having a problem with the first flow when i try to compress the fixed width file this returns the file in its normal form but when i open the file it is all junk inside, please help me with this:

```
<flow name="cibtest" doc:name="cibtestFlow1">
   <file:inbound-endpoint path="c:users\....\in" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
   <gzip-compress-transformer/>
   <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:users\....\out" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "junk inside" is compressed data. Use a gzip decompressor to see what's inside the file.